# Cyclic dependencies in JavaScript modules (ES6)

Tags: javascript, es6-class, es6-modules

I've been reading and testing ES6 modules recently and have used a combination of 2ality and MDN as my source of understanding.

In a large legacy JS web-app that I'm planning to modernise I have circular dependencies and I have found no solution on how to resolve my problem. *I know  that circular dependencies should be avoided as much as possible and my next step after migration will be to clear up as much as I can.*

My test case is as follows:

test.html:

```
<script type="module">
    import B from './B.js';

    console.log(B.moo());
</script>
```

B.js:

```
// B.js
import A from './A.js';

export default class B {
    static moo() {
        return A.boo();
    }
}
```

A.js:

```
// A.js
import B from './B.js';

export default class A extends B {
    static boo() {
        return "Boo";
    }
}
```

From the above, I essentially have just 2 things going on:

1. `B.moo()` calls the static method `A.boo()`
2. `A` extends `B`

However, the above code results in an error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: B is not defined    at A.js:3`

I get that ES6 modules are resolved statically and the error makes sense.  But they're also (*supposed?*) to support cyclic dependencies.

After much messing around I have found a solution that works.  But I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Here is my working solution so far:

test.html:

```
<script type="module">
    import A from './A.js';
    import B from './B.js';

    console.log(B.moo());
</script>
```

B.js:

```
import A from './A.js';

export const B = class B {
    static moo() {
        return A.boo();
    }
}

export {B as default};
```

A.js:

```
import B from './B.js';

export const A = class A extends B {
    static boo() {
        return "Boo";
    }
}

export {A as default};
```

Comment: Couldnt you just move *import A from './A.js';* to the last line in b.js?

Comment: @Jonasw that's certainly cleaner than what I'd come up with - but I'm surprised it worked, I thought I'd read that the order of imported modules did not matter.  I still need to have both A and B imported in test.html too - which is what I'd hoped to avoid.

Comment: "I'm wondering if there's a better way?" - sure, fix your design. Base classes should never call their descendants. Please tell us about your specific problem.

Comment: @georg my example above is a bit contrived to reproduce the issue that I do have.  However your 'never' statement sounds a bit purist.  Especially since we're speaking about static methods here so it is a legitimate use case and one that's not easily refactored out of a JS code base that's several years old...

Comment: The point is, you'll be better off fixing your actual problem (bad design) instead of inventing workarounds to circumvent it.

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how you seem to know the actual problem is bad design.  I know from over 10 years of experience that the design is fine.  I inherited something that's not perfect but the design is sound and I'm trying to clean things up.  You're free to post a useful contribution but otherwise please move along.

Comment: Sorry, how does @JonasW.'s solution work? Using the first thee files given and doing what he he said doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @henry zhang it always depends on the usecase if it works or if you just have to resolve the circular dependency manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching I came across this article: https://medium.com/@rohanjamin/using-scope-to-resolve-circular-dependency-dynamic-loading-issues-in-es6-2ef0244540fa - not sure why I didn't come across it on my previous Google searches.

It rather closely resembles the same code arrangement I have in the code I'm working with and it seems to be working well.  I can foresee that there will be some future issues with tree shaking but I've got Babel to output a list of circular dependencies that we can manually refactor over the next few months.